# The method 'dispose' was called on null in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, widget, focus, dispose

I want to make to do app in flutter, for use of focusNode i write this code ->

```
FocusNode _titleFocus;
FocusNode _descriptionFocus;
FocusNode _todoFocus;


@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
super.initState();
if(widget.task!=null){

  _titleFocus = FocusNode();
  _descriptionFocus = FocusNode();
  _todoFocus = FocusNode();

  }
}

 @override
 void dispose() {
 // TODO: implement dispose
  _titleFocus.dispose();
  _descriptionFocus.dispose();
  _todoFocus.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

I initiate the FocusNode first below the code, this focusNode work correctly in exiting todo task object but when i want to create new one and passing focus one to another it's not working. I use this code for passing focus...

```
focusNode: _titleFocus,
_descriptionFocus.requestFocus();
```

but it goes wrong and show the message ->

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
The method 'dispose' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: dispose()
```

Answer (score 5):

> **"When i want to create new one and passing focus one to another it's not working."**

The `FocusNode` doesn't get instantiated because of your condition in the `initState` method. Hence the error (`The method 'dispose' was called on null.`).

To fix, you can check for the condition before calling `dispose()` on the `FocusNode`s in the `dispose` method.

---

```
 @override
 void dispose() {
 // TODO: implement dispose
if(widget.task!=null){ // check whether it is an existing todo or a new one before calling dispose
_titleFocus.dispose();
  _descriptionFocus.dispose();
  _todoFocus.dispose();
}
  super.dispose();
}
```

UPDATE: Instead of the `IF` checks, you could use the `null aware operator` denoted by `?.` :

Added an example below:

```dart
 @override
 void dispose() {
 // TODO: implement dispose
  _titleFocus?.dispose();
  _descriptionFocus?.dispose();
  _todoFocus?.dispose();
}
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Instead of the if check you could use the null aware operator on each focus node in dispose ie. <focus node>?.dispose()

Comment: Thanks for the tip, updated the answer to specify the `null aware operator` => `?.` can be used instead of `if` checks.

Comment: If my answer helped you with the problem specified in your original post, please accept and upvote. @sazinsamin